# Logstash date filter failed parsing

Tags: java, logstash

I have an issue with date filter. I follow "getting started" guide from logstash doc.
Here is my pastebin with logstash's config and debug : http://pastebin.com/u8YkuStW

> Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"timestamp",
>   :value=>"30/Oct/2014:11:55:08 +0100",
>   :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
>   "30/Oct/2014:11:55:08 +0100" is malformed at "Oct/2014:11:55:08
>   +0100", :level=>:warn, :file=>"logstash/filters/date.rb", :line=>"213"}

I don't understand why date filter don't recognize the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found where is the mistake. You have to precise the locale in the date filter (my logstash is on a french centos)!

With this filter it's ok :

```
  date {
    locale => en
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
```